# Why does a creating a new Date() object from an existing one in Javascript not preserve the milliseconds field?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why does the following code result in minDate having zero milliseconds?

```
maxDate = new Date(2013,0,1,0,0,1,200);
minDate = new Date(maxDate.getTime());
```

I'm looking at this in Chrome if that makes a difference?

Comment: Consier: `minDate = new Date(maxDate)` to save some typing.

Comment: Yeah, I would have done that but I'd been paring down the problem from a larger solution and originally I was subtracted a days worth of milliseconds from the maxdate timestamp.

Comment: `new Date(maxDate - 8.64e7)` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minDate` doesn't have zero for milliseconds. The milliseconds are there in `maxDate` and gets into `minDate`:

```
maxDate = new Date(2013,0,1,0,0,1,200);
console.log(maxDate.getMilliseconds());
minDate = new Date(maxDate.getTime());
console.log(minDate.getMilliseconds());
```

Output:

```
200
200
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2FCvz/

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong but it works fine now. I was logging the result of getTime() to the console but that seems to wek for me too.